# Save and retrieve file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-filesystem

I have difficulty understanding the file save and retrieval in Laravel. I managed to get the file saved into correct path

```
$fileNameWithExt = $request->file('Agreement_file')->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extention  =$request->file('Agreement_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filenameToStore = $fileName . '_' . $lab_id. '.'.$extention;
$request->Agreement_file->storeAs('agreements', $filenameToStore );
```

However not I want to create an a-tag to download the file, but cannot manage to get to download the file.

```
<a href="/storage/app/public/agreements/'. {{$filenameToStore}}" download="{{$filenameToStore}}">{{$filenameToStore}}</a>
```

The file download but I get the error "Failed- Server Problem". I do not want to use a same link as these files are confidential and should not be able to be downloaded outside the app.

Comment: Hi! And what is the inspect element a output?

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

**Step 1:**

Create table files `id | filename | user_id`.

**Step 2:**

Create model File

**Step 3:**

Add file row in table.

```
$fileNameWithExt = $request->file('Agreement_file')->getClientOriginalName();
$fileName = pathinfo($fileNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extention  =$request->file('Agreement_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filenameToStore = $fileName . '_' . $lab_id. '.'.$extention;
$request->Agreement_file->storeAs('agreements', $filenameToStore );

File::create([
   'filename' => $filenameToStore,
   'user_id' => Auth::id()
]);
```

**Step 4:**

Create controller method download.

```
public function download(){
    $filename = $request->input('filename');

    $file = File::where('user_id', Auth::id())
        ->where('filename', $filename)
        ->firstOrFail();

    $path = Storage::path('agreements/' . $filename);

    if(Storage::exists($path)){
        return Response::download($path, $filename);
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**

Replace your link:

```
<a href="/path/download?filename='. {{$filenameToStore}}" download="{{$filenameToStore}}">{{$filenameToStore}}</a>
```

Or you can build it based on the file ID.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Ok I do have a fi;led in my current file to save the file name, thus I do not need to created a new table containing the file name. the download function, should it be in my Controller file where I save or should I put it in the blade file?

Comment: @Johann Download method must be in controller.

Comment: @ IndianCoding can you please send me your email, that I can send you my blade as well as my controler files. I am still lost here

Comment: This is helpful but if my function parameter has ``array $data`` and save data by `` modal::create(['firstname' => $data['firstname'])`` then how can I save file thanks.